# Macos - Heroku error code H=10 (Twitter Opensea.io Sales Bot)

Tags: github, heroku, twitter

I'm facing the problem showing below on HEROKU. I'm using this GitHub Program (https://github.com/dsgriffin/opensea-sales-twitter-bot)
and deployed it 1:1 in Heroku. The current status is that the app is deployed, but I can't open the app. If I try, this message appears.

This is the message:

```
 ug 17 03:50:12 kidpunksbot heroku/router at=error
 code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
 host=kidpunksbot.herokuapp.com request_id=d146801e-6e51-424d-abe1-9b111d06b080
 fwd="79.229.5.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the following service: https://nft-bots.io/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).